# Error pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I already have an error about pointer and function in C++
I got a problem here:
    I try to change value of dimension x of point P

```
....
if ((j % 2) == 0){
            b = P->PGet().XGet() - 1;
            P->PGet().XSet(b);
}
```

and here is the declare of **XGet()** and **XSet()** in class CPoint3D

```
 void CPoint3D::XSet(float ox)
{
    x = ox;
}
float CPoint3D::XGet()
{
    return x;
}
```

for example: **initially, I set P->PGet().XGet() =9**
but after the function:

```
if ((j % 2) == 0){
            b = P->PGet().XGet() - 1;
            P->PGet().XSet(b);
}
```

**The dimension X of P still is 9, nothing change**.
I don't understand why is that, please help me to finish he error. Thanks you very much.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your post to diagnose any problems. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You seem to have `xg` and `xs` mixed up. As it stands, this code is neither complete nor correct, and we can't help you.

Comment: My guess is that prun->pg() returns a copy and not the internal structure. But you did not include the code parts that matter and did not name anything in a way that allows readers to understand the code intent.
I'm guessing xs() is setX() and xg is getX()?

Answer (score 0):

The code: `P->PGet().XSet(8);` Probably does not do what you think it does..

It is most likely that `P->PGet() returns a copy of the "Point" and not the internal structure. The proof of that will be in the definition of PGet()..

My guess is that the function looks something like this: `CPoint3D Prune::PGet() const` This means that the function PGet returns a copy of `CPoint3D`.

and so `P->PGet().XSet(8);` will set the X coordinate on a copy CPoint3D and not internally on P.

Since you have a PGet() on P you should probably have a PSet() on P and do something like:

```
CPoint3D pt = P->PGet();   //Get a copy 
pt.XSet(8);                //Change the copy
P->PSet( pt );             //Update P with the new point
```

Note: It is technically possible to return the internal (non-const) reference of the CPoint3D inside P `CPoint3D& Prune::PGet()` like you would on Java.. but that would allow making changes to P from outside the object and can lead to very weird behavior. I prefer `const CPoint3D& Prune::PGet() const` and use `PSet()`

Comment: Hi, i already fixed my question, please answer me again. Thanks

Comment: I do not write prun->pg().xg() = 9 in my program, I mean I just **give an example** like this. I have written my program with thousand of code lines, I always use this function xg() and xs() but there are no errors except this time. I totally cannot understand that.

Comment: I think my visual has some problems, because when i change code, even new code is wrong it still work, when i rebuild project with wrong code, it still work. so funny